# Bash history enumerated from the end

Tags: bash, cygwin, history

In bash one can `!-1` to execute the `1` command from the history enumerated from the end starting at `0`. But what how can one view history so that mentioned enumeration is shown instead of usual one by built-in means? Of course one can write a simple script for that but I feel like there should be some kind of option for that.

Another question is if there is a way to somehow switch history expansion so that `-` sign would be unnessasary. Say exchanging meaning of `!1` and `!-1`.

Comment: Does `history | tail -r` get anything like what you're after, in the first part of your question?

Comment: @sje397 `tail` doesn't recognize `-r` option. I'm under Cygwin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Showing negative indices is simple to implement.  Just take the length of history (or get it from `history 1`), and subtract it from the index of all other history items.

```
neghistory() {
    local i n s
    read n s < <(history 1)
    history "$@" | while read i s; do
        printf '%5d %s\n' $((i-n-1)) "$s"
    done
}
```

I don't see any built-in ways to affect history's output like this nor change how indices in history expansion works.

Comment: Well, script is quite simple indeed. Thank you. I'll wait to see if there is positive answer to second question.